# Why does a DataIntegrityViolationException in Spring consume an ID, resulting in a gap in the sequence, and how can it be fixed?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, rest

I have a @ControllerAdvice class with an exception handler that catches DataIntegrityViolationException when attempting to save a user with a name that already exists due to a unique constraint in my database. However, when this handler is triggered, it seems to "consume" the ID, and the next successful save operation results in a gap in the ID sequence. How can I fix it?

Handler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleDataIntegrityViolation(DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
        var errorDTO = new ErrorDTO(BAD_REQUEST);
        errorDTO.setMessage("The record with this name already exists");
        errorDTO.setDebugMessage(ex.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage());
        return buildResponseEntity(errorDTO);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ErrorDTO errorDTO) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDTO, errorDTO.getStatus());
    }
}
```

The method in service layer:

```
@Transactional
    public ReaderDTO saveDto(ReaderDTO readerDTO) {
        var reader = readerMapper.readerDTOToReader(readerDTO);
        var savedReader = readersRepository.save(reader);
        return readerMapper.readerToReaderDTO(savedReader);
    }
```

Controller method:

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<ReaderDTO> create(ReaderDTO readerDTO) {
        var savedDto = readerService.saveDto(readerDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(savedDto);
    }
```

and method in interface:

```
@Operation(
            summary = "Create a new reader",
            description = "Create a new reader record",
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "201",
                            description = "Reader created successfully",
                            content = @Content(
                                    mediaType = "application/json",
                                    schema = @Schema(implementation = ReaderDTO.class)
                            )
                    ),
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "400",
                            description = "Bad request",
                            content = @Content(
                                    mediaType = "application/json",
                                    schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorDTO.class)
                            )
                    )
            }
    )
    @PostMapping
    ResponseEntity<ReaderDTO> create(@RequestBody ReaderDTO readerDTO);
```

Thanks in advance

Everything is ok when I use the service method like that

```
 @Transactional
    public ReaderDTO saveDto(ReaderDTO readerDTO) {
        var oneByName = findOneByName(readerDTO.getName());
        if (oneByName.isPresent()) {
            throw new DataIntegrityViolationException("Wow");
        }
        var reader = readerMapper.readerDTOToReader(readerDTO);
        var savedReader = readersRepository.save(reader);
        return readerMapper.readerToReaderDTO(savedReader);
    }
```

but I don't want to use direct throw of exception

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76120200/postgres-consecutive-id-numbers-end-user

Comment: That's how a sequence works. If you don't want this behavior, you can't use a sequence and you have to create your own algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the gap is that an id was provided by a sequence or serial column or equivalent. That id source now moved on to the next higher id, it doesn't role back with the rest of the transaction. It kind of lives outside of transactions.

This is actually important, because creating sequential ids without gap is slow. If you would want to do that you'd have to

1. lock what ever generates your ids.
2. Get the new id
3. Use it
4. eventually complete the transaction, releasing the lock.
   Which basically means you are processing everything that needs an id sequentially.

This is really bad for performance and therefore normally not done.

If there really is a need for sequential ids the process above can be implemented.